# Conversion of a decimal number to a binary number on Fortran

Tags: loops, binary, fortran

I want to write a program that converts a decimal number to a binary number and tha gives the size of that binary number. I have the following code:

```
          program bin
             implicit none
             integer i, count, bin(100), dec
             write(6,*)'Type a number for the conversion'
             read(5,*) dec
             count = 0
                do i = 1,100
                if (mod(dec,2)==0) then
                   bin(i) = 0
                else
                   bin(i) = 1
                end if
                dec = dec/2
                count = count + 1 
                if (dec == 0) then
                   exit  
                end if
                end do
             write(6,*)1,bin(i), i = count
             write(6,*)count
          end program bin
```

I'm having problems with the write(6,*)(1,bin(i),i=count), it shows the message "Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant at", but I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: You say `write(6,*)(1,bin(i),i=count)` but in your code you have `write(6,*)1,bin(i), i = count`. Avoid reading from from 5 and writing to 6, use just `*`, it is safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct form of the implied do loop is

```
  (bin(i), i=1, count)
```

so in full

```
  write(*,*) (bin(i), i=1, count)
```

but you can just use a subarray

```
  write(*,*) bin(1:count)
```

An explicit format will be handy too

```
  write(*,'(i0)') bin(1:count)
```

Of course, storing a single bit (a 0 or 1) in an integer is not too efficient and there are more direct ways to get binary representation in Fortran. See ch21§s answer for an example.

Answer (score 4):

I seriously don't know what you want to achieve with the line

```
write(6,*)1,bin(i), i = count
```

If you want to output the binary representation of an integer, you can always use the `B` format specifier:

```
write(*, '(B64)') n
```

With most modern Fortran Compilers, you can tell it to generate just as many digits as you need by declaring it to be length '0':

```
write(*, '(B0)') n
```

So here's a little program that reads a number, then prints out its binary length and its binary representation using string manipulation:

```
program binary

    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    integer(kind=int64) :: n
    character(len=64) :: bin_representation
    read(*, *) n
    write(bin_representation, fmt='(B0)') n
    write(*, *) len_trim(bin_representation), trim(bin_representation)

end program binary
```