# Decimal to binary conversion in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am new in Fortran so I can't really evaluate where the semantic mistake is. From what I see the syntax is ok and when I build I don't see any mistake from the compiler I have in "Simply Fortran" I didn't find any standard function for binary conversion and I think there aren't any from what I see. Can anyone help me to fix the code so that I got displayed the elements of the array and the respective element in binary ? Thank you in advance for your help.

I think like this it works now.
I initialised the array with given numbers though.
code:

```
program array_binary
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(8) :: numbers
    character(len=32), dimension(8) :: binary_numbers
    integer :: i, j, k
   
    numbers = [8, 9, 3, 4, 89, 6, 7, 8]
    
    do i = 1, 8
        write(*,*) numbers(i)
    end do
   
    do i = 1, 8
        k = numbers(i)
        binary_numbers(i) = ""
        do j = 1, 32
            if (mod(k,2) == 0) then
                binary_numbers(i) = "0" // binary_numbers(i)
            else
                binary_numbers(i) = "1" // binary_numbers(i)
            end if
            k = k / 2
        end do
    end do
    
    do i = 1, 8
        write(*,*) binary_numbers(i)
    end do
end program array_binary
```

Comment: Welcome. What is wrong with the code? What do you need to fix? Does it compile? Any error messages? Or are the results wrong? How exactly wrong? See [ask].

Comment: Hello, I get this as error message  after I do "build": /Users/mariosantoro/Fortran/Hello/Hello.f90:33:3:

   33 | end program array_constructor
      |   1
Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)
f951: Error: Unexpected end of file in '/Users/mariosantoro/Fortran/Hello/Hello.f90'
Error: Last command making (build/Hello.o) returned a bad status
Error: Make execution terminated


* Failed *

Comment: You appear to have more `do`s than `end do`s: please carefully check your loops and [edit] the question with any corrections.

Comment: That said, you can get the string representation in binary [very simply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42915928/3157076) using the `B` edit descriptor.

Comment: you just edited your code to seemingly correct the syntax error - so now what is the problem?

Comment: Yep, now I get the right output as far as the elements of the array are concerned but I get only 0 when the elements are converted

Comment: you divide mod loop need to assign the divided by 2 valiue to decimal_number, at the momnet you just  loop on the same numbe

Comment: 1) please edit your question when you need to bring additional details, do not use comments for that; 2) `binary_z` is an array of strings, and when you write `binary_z = '0'`, **all** the elements are set to `'0'`: I guess that `binary_z(j) = '0'` is what you want; 3) as it appears that that each element is a binary digit, you may declare `character(len=1), dimension(8) :: binary_z`; 4) or alternatively `character(len=8) :: binary_z` and assign a subtring : `binary_z(j:j) = '0'`

Comment: That said the code that is currently displayed in your question has no chance to compile: please update it to your current version.

Comment: I changed something, but I think I didn't quite understood what you meant as it gives  me all 0 as output. I didn't get how could I use binary_z (j) as it doesn't seem to change anything. I still do something wrong I guess.

Comment: 1) You didn't make the change at the right place, you have to change the `binary_z`  assignements that are inside the if-then-else blocks; 2) what you are doing with the `z` is unclear, as you are initializing it in the first outer loop, then you are overwriting it in the third outer loop.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend to use consistent indentation. Put every `end do` exactly below its respective `do` so that you see where each loop starys and when it ends. It is really important for code readability. The indentation (spaces at the start of each line) can be uaed to visualize the structure. Increase the indentation level when entering a construct or a subprogram.

Comment: I guess now it should work apparently

Comment: The code looks better, indeed. Still I don't think it does what you really want: it looks like you want to get the 32 bits binary representation of 8 integer numbers, but you here will get only the representation of the last one, and you have some out of nound access to the `binary_numbers` array

Comment: The last incarnation (there have been sufficient to throw out the meaningfulness of comments) would work if either you add the trim() function to your string or pick out individual elements of the string (as in PierU's answer). With the trim function: binary_numbers(i) = "0" // trim( binary_numbers(i) ) and similarly for "1". I agree with @francescalus' suggestion of the 'b' format specifier, but the poster's approach would generalise to other radices(?) than 2. I would break off the conversion part to a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the solution, as it's better if you get it by yourself. However it looks like you have troubles with how arrays of strings work. Here is how:

`character(len=32) :: string` is a 32 characters string. You can access substrings with the `:` notation

```
string = "abcdef"
write(*,*) string        ! full string
write(*,*) string(3:5)   ! 3 characters substring
write(*,*) string(2:2)   ! 1 character substring
                         ! note that string(2) gives an error
string(1:3) = "ABC"      ! write in a subtring
write(*,*) string
```

results in:

```
abcdef
cde
b
ABCdef
```

Now the arrays of string:

`character(len=32) :: string(8)` is a 8 elements arrays, each element being a 32 characters string. This is equivalent to
`character(len=32), dimension(8) :: string`

When indexing arrays of strings, the first index level refers to the array elements, and the second index level refers to the subtrings:

- `string(2)` is the 2nd element of the array, and is a full 32 characters string. It is equivalent to `string(2)(:)`
- `string(2)(10:16)` is a 7 characters substring of the 2nd element of the array
- `string(:)(10:10)` is a 8 elements array of 1 character subtrings
- `string(4:6)` is a 3 elements subarray of 32 characters strings

Comment: Thans for the answer. I will review it carefully.

Comment: But this is the wrong approach to converting a decimal integer to its binary representation in Fortran. OP should pay careful attention to @francescalus' second comment above.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I agree, but let's take it as an exercise to learn how to handle arrays of strings.